# Household grid: extracting information across columns to fill lead variable

Tags: r, replace, datagrid

I am currently working on a household data set from Rwanda. Here, we interviewed teenagers about various topics. As part of the data collection, we compiled household grids. We basically asked the teenagers to provide us some information about the household members they live with. The result is a household grid that might look as follows:

```
df<-data.frame(read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
          ID Age Rel_1 Age_1 Rel_2 Age_2 Rel_3 Age_3
          1   .    Self  12   Dad    40   Mom   38  
          2   .     Dad   50  Mom    50   Self  22
          3   .    Granddad  75  Mom  40   Self 15
          4   .     Dad  45  Self 15   Mom 44   
          5   .    Mom 50 Sister 18  Self 22
          "))
```

Each row refers to the teenager. Hence, in this example that I made up, we see three household members, including the teenager herself. The second column is empty.

Based on the information in the household grid (consisting of columns `Rel_1`, `Age_1`, `Rel_2`, `Age_2`, `Rel_3`, `Age_3`), I would like to determine the age of the teenager we interviewed.

I would basically need to look up which of the three members has been marked as "Self". The columns `Rel_$` basically indicate the relationship of that household member with the teenager. In some cases, it is the dad or the mother etc. Whenever a column speaks of "Self", it means that household member is the teenager.

Basically, one needs to look up in what Rel-column we find "Self". The corresponding entry in the age column is then the age of the teenager. For example, in the case of respondent 1, `Rel_1` is "Self". Hence, the entry in column `Age_1` is the age of the teenager. It is 12. In the case of the second respondent, it is 22.

I can extract the information from the household grid (consisting of columns `Rel_1`, `Age_1`, `Rel_2`, `Age_2`, `Rel_3`, `Age_3`) to fill the empty column `Age` manually by writing many codes. However, this is not an elegant solution. Also, my household grid consists of 15 members and around 20 variables. Hence, it would require lost of coding, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R `apply` function is used as a compact way of doing loops such as the loop over the rows of `df` in your example.  Also for this case, the expression operating on the row data is a bit complex so we'll implement the logic with an anonymous function defined by `function(x).`  Code looks like

```
df$Age <- as.integer(apply(df, 1, function(x) x[which(x == "Self")+1]))
```

Here `x` is a character vector contain a single row of `df`.  `which(x == "Self")+1` returns the number of the column containing `Age` for `Self` just as in `jayashree rout's` code.  Rather than storing this in the intermediate variable `a`, it's used directly in `x[ ]` to select the column containing value of `Age`.   `apply` forms either a character vector or a list(if `Self` was not found for a row) containing these results.  This is converted to an integer vector and then stored in `df$Age`.

The result should be the same as in `jayashree rout's` code and he should get credit for the algorithm.   `apply` and its family members (`sapply`, `lapply`, `mapply`) as well as anonymous functions are used quite commonly in R.  Since you indicated that you were looking for more compact code, I thought you might find this version of interest.

Comment: ! Thank you so much! I just realised I have not responded yet. Thanks for the code and the explanations!

Comment: If you find that an answer works for you, you should check Accept.  This will both provide a bit of recognition for the person who took the time to work out the answer and also lets other SO users know that the answer is a solution to the problem you posted.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know this. I just accepted! Your help is really much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, you want to fill the age column with the age of teenager (the age of self). I pasted the code below to do so, hope it will be helpful

```
df_3<-df
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
 {
  a<-which(df[i,]=="Self")+1
   df_3[i,2]<-df[i,a]
 }
```

Comment: You might consider using an R `apply` function to handle the loop over rows and then putting your logic in a one-line anonymous function, something of the form `df$Age <- apply(df, 1, function(x) .. your logic.. )` .

Comment: Hey both! thank you so much! Both works amazing. Given that i work with a real data set I immediately run into another problem. But I will now post a new question. Cheers!

Comment: @WaltS, did you have the following in mind: `df$Age <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {a<-which(df[x,]=="Self")+1; df[x,2]<-df[x,a]})`? It does not seem to work in my case. Any idea what I did wrong?